# I want to implement Toast into my react native app

Tags: react-native

```
import Toast from 'react-native-simple-toast';
```

I am  using this library to use react-native toast ,but this library is giving error every time .

please suggest me a library that could work.
I need to implement Toast in my app.

Comment: share you toast component.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Toast from 'react-native-toast-message';

function SomeComponent() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    Toast.show({
      text1: 'Hello',
      text2: 'This is some something '
    });
  }, []);

  return <View />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Toast from 'react-native-simple-toast';

Toast.show(`PLAY SERVICES NOT AVAILABLE`, Toast.LONG)
```

Try with this. if not work then let me know which type of error you got?

You can also use Platform base like this

```
if(Platform.OS == 'ios'){
   Toast.show(`PLAY SERVICES NOT AVAILABLE`, Toast.LONG)
}else{
   ToastAndroid.showWithGravityAndOffset('PLAY SERVICES NOT AVAILABLE',ToastAndroid.LONG, ToastAndroid.BOTTOM, 25,50)
}
```